# How do i get the index of the highest number of sum value from all rows in a 2d array

Tags: java

```
 0 1 2 3

0  5 10 1 5 
1  1 2 1 15 
2  8 7 5 3 
3  6 1 12 1
```

This is a 2d array, i need to find the sum of all rows and the ouput should print the index of highest sum value.

My code gives me the sum 23 for row 2, but i want the answer 2 (index) instead of 23 (sum)

```
public static int indexofHighestRowSum (int[][] a)
   {
        int i,j, sum, n=0;
        for (i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            sum =0;
            for (j=0; j<a[0].length; j++)
             {
                  sum += a[i][j];
             }

             if (sum >n)
               n=sum;`
        }
        return a[index];
    }
```

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Save `i` in n instead of `sum`

Comment: and then return n; good answer !                                                                                  But i used index =0 and then when sum>n i did index = i and return index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the index, next to the current highest sum. Then you can return the index of the highest row encountered:

```
public static int indexofHighestRowSum(int[][] a) {
    int i, j, sum, n = 0, index = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
            sum += a[i][j];
        }

        if (sum > n) {
            n = sum;
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```